# Java / Android package name for example code

Tags: java, android

Is there a legitimate 'generic' package name I can use to open-source some demo code?

I want to provide the source of a demo Android app as 'public-domain' via Google Code or wherever but I'd like the source package to be 'generic'. In other words, I do have a registered domain which I normally use for package naming but I'd rather not have that for demo code.

I sometimes see example code packages using `com.example.some.package` (for example) but that's a registered domain name. Is there any common accepted way of naming a generic package which doesn't use someone's registered domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

example.com, example.net and example.org are [reserved by IANA](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt) for just such a purpose actually.

Comment: Oh wow - I can't believe I didn't find that when I was searching. Obviously having a bad search day. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While Sean Owen is right, I would use the TLD `example` and or `invalid`. That would mean that your package would be `example.mistersquonk....` and not `com.example.mistersquonk...`

Comment: It was a tough decision but I accepted Sean's answer as he provided the link for the RFC which I hadn't come across before. Just lucky timing that he got there first but I up-voted you for emphasising the use of the TLDs themselves. Thanks again.

Comment: I would have done the same (in fact I upvoted Sean, too); I just wanted to point out this other possibility.