# sqlite database not created

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using standard approach which I learned from popular notepad example for building my *first* app.
But I got stuck into a strange problem.
The SQLite database file (.db) is not being created in /data/data/package/databases. I have cross checked manifest file and OpenHelper file from HeadFirst android dev. Book ( I am using it as a reference ) but I found myself unable to figure out why the database file is not created..
Are there any special permissions or something we need to switch on to get it working??
strange thing is that its working fine for pre-loaded examples. means '.db' file is created for notepad example but when I try, it fails. :(
here are my files.

*Package - database.test*

**1. AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Database_testActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**2.TestOpenHelper.java**

```
package database.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TestOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

TestOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context,"mydb.db",null,1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.execSQL("create table test_1 " + " (field1 integer primary key, field2 integer);");
}
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    database.execSQL("drop table if exists test1");
    onCreate(database);
}
}
```

**3.Database_testActivity.java**

```
package database.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Database_testActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_list);
    TestAdapter ta = new TestAdapter();
    listview.setAdapter(ta);

    TestOpenHelper openHelper = new TestOpenHelper(this);
}
}
```

I know its a very basic question, but I have been trying to solve this for last fifteen days and now I am completely frustrated.
Please help ..

Comment: You should use `Log` in various places and monitor `logcat` to trace what's happening. Also I may be wrong but have you tried using "mydb" for the db name in the `TestOpenHelper` constructor? As I said, I may be wrong but I can't help feeling using a filename extension (as in "mydb.db") might cause problems.

Comment: can you throw some light on `using Log`. I have tried various names but nothing happens.
thank you

Comment: also every app. in /data/data starts with com.android.something but mine does not. can it be the reason of my problem ??

Comment: Put something like `Log.d("MyAppName", "In TestOpenHelper constructor");`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change this:

```
database.execSQL("create table test_1 " + " (field1 integer primary key, field2 integer)");
```

and this `TestOpenHelper openHelper = new TestOpenHelper(this);` change to `SQLiteDatabase db = new TestOpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();`

You really didn't created database, you only create instance of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` but for create or open database you have to use `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` method.

Exactly from docs:

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing.

Comment: your code didn't work because you never create database you only create instance of your SQLiteOpenHelper man :-) for create database you have to call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` this methods create / open your database. when your database is already created, so this methods will be always only open your database.

Comment: @MisterSquonk so it happens sometimes :-)

Comment: hawaii.five-0 and @MisterSquonk : I want to ask one more thing.  every app. in /data/data starts with com.android.something but mine does not. how do I bring my app in that standard folder ??

Comment: you should create package com.android.bond.myCustomDatabase

Comment: is it necessary that every app should be addressed like this ?? thanks for helping newbie..

Comment: @bond : Your package name should be something unique to yourself (or your company). If you don't have a registered domain name then just use something like `com.example.mypackage.myapp`. See the answers to the question I asked about 'generic' package names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872787/java-android-package-name-for-example-code I do have a domain name so I name my packages starting `com.mydomain.mypackage.`. You shouldn't use `com.android` as `android.com` is a registered domain name.