# Can't get a database to be created

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database but when I open the file explorer on the app there are no databases and there's no folder where the database should be, but that's probably because the database was never created. Below is my code. ny help is appreciated

DatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
        public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
        public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
        public static final String COL_3 = "I1Q1";
        public static final String COL_4 = "I1Q2";
        public static final String COL_5 = "I2Q1";
        public static final String COL_6 = "I2Q2";
        public static final String COL_7 = "I3Q1";
        public static final String COL_8 = "I3Q2";
        public static final String COL_9 = "I4Q1";
        public static final String COL_10 = "I4Q2";
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,I1Q1 TEXT,I1Q2 TEXT,I2Q1 TEXT,I2Q2 TEXT,I3Q1 TEXT,I3Q2 TEXT,I4Q1 TEXT,I4Q2 TEXT)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
}
```

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for SQLiteOpenHelper might be relevant: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite database not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888227/sqlite-database-not-created)

Answer (score 1):

You have created the `DatabaseHelper` object in `onCreate()` but you have not used your `SQLiteDatabase` yet.  That is why the database was never created.

Call `myDb.getWrittableDatabase()` in `onCreate()` and your database will be created after.

Answer (score 0):

As Skemelio answered, you need to perform any task using the database for it to be actually created.

A nice advice is to use a ORM instead of writing all the code for the Database yourself.
I recommend using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)